# ERRO ao chamar um programa quando seleciono uma opção no menu

Tags: cobol

Boa tarde,

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Cobol utilizando screen section e não consigo chamar um programa de cadastro de clientes quando seleciono uma opção no menu que criei em outro programa. Estou utilizando o compilador GnuCOBOL.

Utilizei o comando call:

> CALL "CADASTRO-CLIENTES" USING BY CONTENT SUBMENU-IN-WS
>   CANCEL "CADASTRO-CLIENTES"

Mas dá erro abaixo:

> attempt to reference unallocated memory (signal SIGSEGV) abnormal
>   termination - file contents may be incorrect

Tenho que chamar um programa passando parâmetros (utilizar o Using)?

Desde já agradeço.